# Clone <select> without the selected value of the first <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two dropdowns on my website.

The first one is being populated using an ajax call to my database which returns some json.

I would like the second one to be an exact copy of the first one, but with one option less: the option that is selected in the first dropdown.

Is there a convenient way to do this within jQuery?

Here's what I tried so far:

```
$('#first').find('option').clone().find('option:selected').remove().end().appendTo('#second');
```

but this only clones it, without removing the selected option.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: $('#first option').clone().appendTo('#second').filter(":selected").remove()

Comment: you can try this :-                                                                       $('#second option[value=' + $('first option:selected').val() + ']').remove();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter out the selected option using the [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method and then append the cloned collection to the second dropdown:

```js
$('#first option').not(':selected').clone().appendTo('#second');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="first">
  <option>1</option>
  <option selected>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>

<select id="second"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) after appending the clone to new node like :

```
$('#first option').clone().appendTo('#second').filter(":selected").remove();
```

See below snippet :

```js
$('#first option').clone().appendTo('#second').filter(":selected").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="first">
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
  <option selected >three</option>
  <option>Four</option>
</select>

<select id="second">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`:not()`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp) selector. Also you can add `change` event and instead of appending just change html. That way it is updating anytime you change a value.

```js
var $first = $("#first");
$first.on('change', function() {
  $('#second').html($first.find('option:not(:selected)').clone());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="first">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>

<select id="second"></select>
```